# Is there a way to expose the Prometheus UI in openshift 4.13?

Tags: openshift, prometheus, grafana

I am using openshift 4.13 and I want to access prometheus UI.I have found article that explains about it on 4.11 as bellow:

```
oc -n openshift-monitoring rsh pod/prometheus-0  socat tcp-l:5050,fork,reuseaddr tcp:127.0.0.1:9090 &
oc port-forward -n openshift-monitoring pod/prometheus-k8s-0 5050:5050
```

but whe i run `socat tcp-l:5050,fork,reuseaddr tcp:127.0.0.1:9090 &` I get Error that **socat is not in $PATH** and it fails.I tried to install socat on prometheus-0 pod but it dosent allow me to that.How can I access prometheus UI directly in openshift 4.13?